# Lock cell in a range after text input using password different from sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel VBA and I can't find my answer anywhere. In my Worksheet "Follow-Up Log" I would like cells with no text in the range `A1:A70` to allow user edits (then automatically lock after the change) while those cells with text are password protected at all times. I would also like the range to use a different password than the worksheet and for the user to enter in the password anytime they wish to edit a cell with text in the range.

I am hoping to apply the same code to ranges `B1:B70`, `K1:K70`, but a different password for each range, all of which are different from the worksheet. Overall I intend to have 4 passwords for this single sheet.

The current code I'm using locks cells after the text has been entered but it's changing the Worksheet password instead of just the cells and you only enter the password once. Does this make sense? Here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim blnUnlockedAllCells As Boolean
Const RangeToLock As String = "A2:A70" '<<  adjust to suit

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not blnUnlockedAllCells Then
    Me.Cells.Locked = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Range(CStr(RangeToLock)).SpecialCells(2).Locked = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    blnUnlockedAllCells = True
    Me.Protect Password:="pwd", userinterfaceonly:=True
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(CStr(RangeToLock))) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Target) Then Target.Locked = True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to lock them. I just recorded this macro to figure out how to do it for multiple ranges:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Range1", Range:=.Range("G8:J10"), Password:="qq"
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Range2", Range:=.Range("K11:L12"), Password:="aa"
End With
```

But keep in mind that if the person knows how to open the code window, they will be easily able to see your passwords.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. It allows cells with text to be edited and then wants a debug for empty cells.

Comment: Even with the edits it's not working. Being new to VBA I'm not sure how to fix it to make it work. Should I be able to just copy and Paste it directly into by Private Sub Worksheet_Change and just update the ranges from G/K to my ranges and edit the passwords? It keeps telling me there is an expected: expression.

Comment: The event you put it in makes a difference. You may want to rethink how this is going to work. You may be better of not doing it using code and instead just set it up manually.

Comment: Using `Worksheet_Change` just does not make sense to me.

Comment: Like I said I am new to VBA so I really have no idea how it works, I'm learning and is why I'm asking for help. If you could provide a clear and detailed explanation that would be more helpful then just saying it doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you are adding a password protected range in the `Worksheet_Change` event, you will be trying to add a password every time a cell's contents changes, which I doubt is what you want. It would make more sense to just set it up using the interface once.

Comment: Would this mean it's trying to make the change within the Worksheet regardless of the cell range? Because what I'm hoping is that once the cells contents have text in it, it requires a password every time someone wants to make edits in it. So, for example, let's say cell A3 is blank I write in it, I want it to lock. Then when I go to edit text in cell A2 I enter in the password. I then realize I made an error in cell A3 so I am asked to enter the password again before making the changes. The goal is to prevent accidental changes to cells once the text has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

The code "setupranges" can set up the ranges and passwords to edit. This does all the work. Copy and paste both of the following subroutines into a new module (insert a module). Make sure you change the passwords to any you have already set.

```
Sub setupranges(wsname As String, rangeX As String)
Dim rangea, rangeb, rangek As String
Dim pwda, pwdb, pwdk As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim pwdws As String

Set Ws = Worksheets(wsname)
rangea = "A1:A70"
rangeb = "B1:B70"
rangek = "K1:K70"
pwda = "aaa"
pwdb = "bbb"
pwdk = "kkk"
pwdws = "pwd"

On Error Resume Next
Ws.Unprotect Password:=pwdws
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case rangeX
    Case Is = "all"
        Call deleterangeifexists(Ws, "a")
        Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="arange",Range:=Ws.Range(rangea), Password:=pwda
        Call deleterangeifexists(Ws, "b")
        Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="brange", Range:=Ws.Range(rangeb), Password:=pwdb
        Call deleterangeifexists(Ws, "k")
        Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="krange", Range:=Ws.Range(rangek), Password:=pwdk
    Case Is = "a"
        Call deleterangeifexists(Ws, "arange")
        Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="arange", Range:=Ws.Range(rangea), Password:=pwda
    Case Is = "b"
        Call deleterangeifexists(Ws, "brange")
        Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="brange",Range:=Ws.Range(rangeb), Password:=pwdb
    Case Is = "k"
        Call deleterangeifexists(Ws, "krange")
        Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="krange", Range:=Ws.Range(rangek), Password:=pwdk
End Select
Ws.Protect Password:=pwdws, userinterfaceonly:=True
End Sub
```

You'll get an error if the range already exists when you try to add it, so this deletes the defined range if it already exists.

```
Sub deleterangeifexists(Ws As Worksheet, Title As String)
Dim rangetocheck As AllowEditRange

For Each rangetocheck In Ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges
    If rangetocheck.Title = Title Then
        rangetocheck.Delete
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Then you have to call setupranges from your worksheet e.g. 
    call setupranges("sheet1","all") 
would reset all passwords for all ranges.
    call setupranges("sheet1","arange") 
would reset the password for the range in column A only.

I would suggest either worksheet_change or worksheet_selectionchange depending on how you want your workbook to behave.
With Worksheet_change bear in mind that your user might unlock a range, then not change anything so your routine wouldn't run and the range would remain unlocked. With Worksheet_selectionchange the code's going to run with every change of cell focus which might be slow. One of them gives you as Target the cell you're now in and one gives you the cell you came from and that might make it easier or harder for you.

Either way, your worksheet code will have:
    If condition is true (whatever condition you want to measure) Then
       call setupranges("sheet1","all")
    End If

Comment: I can't seem to get this one to work either. It doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. I have placed it in the Worksheet coding area should it be in the workbook coding area or does it matter? Wish I had more experience with this.

Comment: I've added some extra information that hopefully will help. I can't really be precise on the worksheet code as it depends on the actual behaviour you want to happen which isn't clear enough in your question. Hopefully there's enough info for you to work it out with some searching on worksheet_change and worksheet_selectionchange events. I also have a flaky keyboard and noticed a couple of extraneous characters in the code which I've now deleted. If you copy it again hopefully it will do something.

Comment: Oh Ok, I see what you're saying. I think for my purposes I would want selection change because the ultimate goal is to prevent any unintentional changes by any users. I'm still having some issues but I'm going to try to play with it for a bit to see if I can get it to work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.